# Javascript code pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, modules

I have been working on a javascript heavy project. There are sales, purchases, reports etc. What I've done is created a separate module for each i.e. a separate module for each i.e. a separate one for sale, one for purchase and so on. I am posting one of my modules, all the others have same structure. Can anyone please review it. Is there anything wrong with it or is everything okay. Any changes that I may want to consider to make it more better i.e. mantainable:

```
var navigation = {

init : function (){
    navigation.bindUI();

    $('.ReportViews').addClass('active');
    $('.stockNavReports').addClass('active');
},

bindUI : function () {
    $("#btnReset").on('click', function (){
        navigaiton.resetReport();
    });

    $("#btnShow").on('click', function (){

        var fromEl = $('#txtStart');
        var toEl = $('#txtEnd');
        var groupBy = navigation.getGroupingCriteria();         

        if (navigation.validDateRange(fromEl.val(), toEl.val())) {
            navigation.fetchReportData(fromEl.val(), toEl.val(), groupBy);
        }
        else{
            fromEl.addClass('input-error');
            toEl.addClass('input-error');
        }

    });
},

getGroupingCriteria : function () {
    return $('input[name="grouping"]:checked').val().toLowerCase();
},

fetchReportData : function (startDate, endDate, groupBy) {

    if (typeof navigation.dTable != 'undefined') {
        navigation.dTable.fnDestroy();
        $('#navigationRows').empty();
    }       

    $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "index.php/report/getNavigationReportData",                
            data: { startDate : startDate, endDate : endDate, groupBy : groupBy },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function () {
                // console.log(this.data);
             },
            complete: function () { },
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.length !== 0) {
                    $("#datatable_StockNavigationRows").fadeIn();


                    var prevDate = "";
                    var prevVrnoa = "";
                    var prevGodown_1 = "";
                    var prevGodown_2 = "";

                    if (result.length != 0) {

                        var navigationRows = $("#navigationRows");

                        $.each(result, function (index, elem) {

                            var obj = { };

                            obj.SERIAL = navigationRows.find('tr').length+1;
                            obj.VRNOA = elem.VRNOA;
                            obj.REMARKS = (elem.REMARKS) ? elem.REMARKS : "Not Available";
                            obj.QTY = (elem.QTY) ? elem.QTY : "Not Available";
                            obj.GODOWN_1 = (elem.GODOWN_1) ? elem.GODOWN_1 : "Not Available";
                            obj.GODOWN_2 = (elem.GODOWN_2) ? elem.GODOWN_2 : "Not Available";
                            obj.VRDATE = (elem.VRDATE) ? elem.VRDATE.substring(0,10) : "Not Available";

                            if (groupBy === 'date') {

                                if (prevDate != obj.VRDATE) {

                                    // Create the heading for this new voucher. 
                                    var source   = $("#report-dhead-template").html();
                                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                                    var html = template(obj);

                                    navigationRows.append(html);

                                    // Reset the previous voucher to current voucher.
                                    prevDate = obj.VRDATE;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (groupBy === 'vrnoa') {

                                if (prevVrnoa != obj.VRNOA) {

                                    // Create the heading for this new voucher. 
                                    var source   = $("#report-vhead-template").html();
                                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                                    var html = template(obj);

                                    navigationRows.append(html);

                                    // Reset the previous voucher to current voucher.
                                    prevVrnoa = obj.VRNOA;
                                }
                            }

                            else if (groupBy === 'godown_1') {

                                if (prevGodown_1 != obj.GODOWN_1) {

                                    // Create the heading for this new voucher. 
                                    var source   = $("#report-g1head-template").html();
                                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                                    var html = template(obj);

                                    navigationRows.append(html);

                                    // Reset the previous voucher to current voucher.
                                    prevGodown_1 = obj.GODOWN_1;
                                }
                            }

                            else if (groupBy === 'godown_2') {

                                if (prevGodown_2 != obj.GODOWN_2) {

                                    // Create the heading for this new voucher. 
                                    var source   = $("#report-g2head-template").html();
                                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                                    var html = template(obj);

                                    navigationRows.append(html);

                                    // Reset the previous voucher to current voucher.
                                    prevGodown_2 = obj.GODOWN_2;
                                }
                            }

                            // Add the item of the new voucher
                            var source   = $("#report-item-template").html();
                            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                            var html = template(obj);

                            navigationRows.append(html);
                        });
                    }
                }

                navigation.bindGrid();
            },

            error: function (result) {
                //$("*").css("cursor", "auto");
                $("#loading").hide();
                alert("Error:" + result);
            }
        });     

},

bindGrid : function() {
    // $("input[type=checkbox], input:radio, input:file").uniform();
    var dontSort = [];
    $('#datatable_StockNavigationRows thead th').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('no_sort')) {
            dontSort.push({ "bSortable": false });
        } else {
            dontSort.push(null);
        }
    });
    navigation.dTable = $('#datatable_StockNavigationRows').dataTable({
        // Uncomment, if datatable not working
        // "sDom": "<'row-fluid table_top_bar'<'span12'<'to_hide_phone' f>>>t<'row-fluid control-group full top' <'span4 to_hide_tablet'l><'span8 pagination'p>>",
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid table_top_bar'<'span12'<'to_hide_phone'<'row-fluid'<'span8' f>>>'<'pag_top' p> T>>t<'row-fluid control-group full top' <'span4 to_hide_tablet'l><'span8 pagination'p>>",
        "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "aoColumns": dontSort,
        "bSort": false,
        "iDisplayLength" : 100,
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "js/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [{ "sExtends": "print", "sButtonText": "Print Report", "sMessage" : "Stock Navigation Report" }]
        }
    });
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        "s`": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
    });
},

validDateRange  : function (from, to){
    if(Date.parse(from) > Date.parse(to)){
       return false
    }
    else{
       return true;
    }
},  

resetReport : function (){
    $(".printBtn")
    $("#datatable_navigationRows").hide();
}
}
navigation.init();
```

Comment: Do you intend for each module to use it's own global namespace object, rather than just have one master namespace object that each module could plug its own object into?

Comment: I have placed each of the object in a separate file and each page that intends to use that object, loads the file and uses it.

Comment: Your `$.ajax` success callback is **way** to big and cries out for refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short,

your code looks good until `$.ajax` where far to many things happen, more specifically too many things happen in `success`.

The funny thing there is that it would look already a lot better if you took a generic approach to deal with the grouping.

Maybe you can have a `groupingConfig` object :

```
var groupingConfigs = 
{
  date     : { template : '#report-dhead-template'  , fieldName : 'VRDATE'   },
  vrnoa    : { template : '#report-vhead-template'  , fieldName : 'VRNOA'    },
  godown_1 : { template : '#report-g1head-template' , fieldName : 'GODOWN_1' },
  godown_2 : { template : '#report-g1head-template' , fieldName : 'GODOWN_1' }
}
```

then, before the `$.each(` you can get the groupingConfig

```
var groupingConfig = groupingConfigs[groupBy];
```

and within the `$.each(` you can simply

```
if (groupingConfig)
{
  if (previousValue != obj[groupingConfig.fieldName])
  {
    // Create the heading for this new group. 
    var source   = $( groupingConfig.template ).html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(obj);

    navigationRows.append(html);
    //Reset the previous group value
    previousValue = obj[groupingConfig.fieldName];
  }
}
```

Also, the below creation of the dataTable looks all kind of wrong:

```
navigation.dTable = $('#datatable_StockNavigationRows').dataTable({
    // Uncomment, if datatable not working
    // "sDom": "<'row-fluid table_top_bar'<'span12'<'to_hide_phone' f>>>t<'row-fluid control-group full top' <'span4 to_hide_tablet'l><'span8 pagination'p>>",
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid table_top_bar'<'span12'<'to_hide_phone'<'row-fluid'<'span8' f>>>'<'pag_top' p> T>>t<'row-fluid control-group full top' <'span4 to_hide_tablet'l><'span8 pagination'p>>",
    "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "aoColumns": dontSort,
    "bSort": false,
    "iDisplayLength" : 100,
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "js/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [{ "sExtends": "print", "sButtonText": "Print Report", "sMessage" : "Stock Navigation Report" }]
    }
});
```

- Hungarian notation, don't do that
- sDom is a super long string without any comment
- the commented sDom has a superfluous comment
- bJQueryUI ?

Finally,

```
validDateRange  : function (from, to){
    if(Date.parse(from) > Date.parse(to)){
       return false
    }
    else{
       return true;
    }
},
```

should really be

```
validDateRange  : function (from, to)
{
  return !(Date.parse(from) > Date.parse(to));
},
```